# What kind of query does the Search class take in?

Tags: search, aem

I have a page using the [Search](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/Search.html) class. Right now it takes in just the fulltext of the search text given. (search.getQuery() return "searchtext".) Unfortunately this is also picking up items that are not of the type 'cq:Page'. I know there is the Querybuilder which takes in the type=cq:Page parameter but when I put this into search.setQuery() the search returns nothing.

I have tried putting in "fulltext=searchtext&type=cq:Page" and it returns nothing.

So what is the format I need to put into the query or is it not possible to add a parameter like that to the Search class?

Answer (score 0):

The `setQuery()` method is used to set the **search term** and not used to set the query to execute.

i.e., If you want to search for "foo", then you do `search.setQuery("foo");`

The Search class uses [SimpleSearch](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/SimpleSearch.html) to perform the full text search. As such, SimpleSearch  implements a simple search with a few additions to the search logic. You might be able to modify the path to search and the properties to search, start and limit for the results.

In your case, you should consider using [Query](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/Query.html) and [QueryBuilder](http://dev.day.com/content/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/QueryBuilder.html).

Check the [Querybuilder docs](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html) which provides detailed info on how to implement this.